# How to use node on localhost with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

My understanding is that, in this setup I run a websocket server(node) on localhost and use the Nginx reverse proxy that sits in front of it to handle the handshake and persistent connection.

The problem that I'm facing is:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'domain.com' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
> 'ws://domain.com:8020/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint
> must be available over WSS.
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure
> WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over
> HTTPS.

So, do I need to have another certificate for the websocket as well ?

Here is the nginx config:

```
http {
...

upstream websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

    server {
        listen 8020;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout 1d;
            proxy_send_timeout 1d;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate     /location/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /location/cert-key.pem;

        root /var/www/html/app;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {        
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    }


}
----------------------------------------
Node:
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080})

Client:
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://domain.com:8020')
```

Should note that everything works while using `http`, just not sure how to make it work with `https`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just hat to move the `ssl_certificate` and `sl_certificate_key` in the `http` block, new to nginx but I'm guessing that way they get inherited in both server blocks.

Also change `ws` to `wss` in js.

```
http {
...

ssl on; # or use listen ssl on is deprecated

ssl_certificate     /location/cert.pem;
sl_certificate_key /location/cert-key.pem;


upstream websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

    server {
        listen 8020;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout 1d;
            proxy_send_timeout 1d;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        root /var/www/html/app;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {        
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    }


}
----------------------------------------
Node:
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080})

Client:
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com:8020')
```